# apache - my .htaccess doesn't work only for 1 sub-domain and work for other

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I'm using Ubuntu wizzy as my local server and then I set up domain there which are

- domain.svr
- api.domain.svr
- adm.domain.svr

And here is the problem. I've create exactly same configuration for all of them but why only adm.domain.svr doesn't work? It's always response 404 when I goes to `http://adm.domain.svr/site/dashboard/` but it's okay when I try `http://api.domain.svr/site/dashboard/`

Here is my configuration

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin localhost@gmail.com
      ServerName  domain.svr

      DocumentRoot /home/shaf/web/domain.dev/frontend/web
      <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride all
      </Directory>
      <Directory /home/shaf/web/domain.dev/frontend/web>
           Require all granted
           Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
           AllowOverride all
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog /home/shaf/log/domain-error.log
      LogLevel warn

      CustomLog /home/shaf/log/domain-access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin localhost@gmail.com
      ServerName  adm.domain.svr

      DocumentRoot /home/shaf/web/domain.dev/backend/web
      <Directory /home/shaf/web/domain.dev/backend/web>
           Require all granted
           Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
           AllowOverride all
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog /home/shaf/log/domain-adm-error.log
      LogLevel warn

      CustomLog /home/shaf/log/domain-adm-access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin localhost@gmail.com
      ServerName  api.domain.svr

      DocumentRoot /home/shaf/web/domain.dev/api/web
      <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride all
      </Directory>
      <Directory /home/shaf/web/domain.dev/api/web>
           Require all granted
           Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
           AllowOverride all
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog /home/shaf/log/domain-api-error.log
      LogLevel warn

      CustomLog /home/shaf/log/domain-api-access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

and here is my .htaccess which I placed on every domain web folder

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Please give me advice about this, I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve this by duplicate another directory to adm and try it but fail, so I create another 1 host so I have 4 host. 1 is duplicate for adm and it's work perfectly. I still didn't know what happen but seems only that folder didn't read the htaccess and I'm sure of it because I already try to swap sub domain but only adm folder doesn't read the htaccess file.

So here is my conclusion and I don't know this is correct or not but apache has cache of htaccess so I need to hard refresh the apache (only restart apache doesn't work because I already tried it several times and nothing happen) so maybe you need to restart your OS / Server and if you doesn't want it, try my way.

Answer (score 0):

Your ServerName  domain.svr is wrong. Apache can not route it. Try to rename it to adm.domain.svr

Comment: All these configs are vhost on the same machine, right?! Where should apache know which vhost is responsible for adm.domain.svr?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get what do you mean. but indeed, that's on the same machine, I try to open adm.domain.svr and of course it's work but it doens't read .htaccess and different with 2 other which read .htaccess.

Comment: You can try www.domain.svr as the ServerName in your first vHost config.

Comment: wait wait, the problem isn't on domain.svr but adm.domain.svr doesn't read htaccess file.